# Why is my @JsProperty not preserving the name in javascript?

Tags: gwt, gwt-jsinterop

I have the following class:

```
@JsType
public class Options {

    @JsProperty
    public boolean extractUrlsWithoutProtocol;

    public Options(boolean extractUrlsWithoutProtocol) {
        this.extractUrlsWithoutProtocol = extractUrlsWithoutProtocol;
    }
}
```

Now I pass it into a javascript method and when I use developer tools to inspect I get that property name is `extractUrlsWithoutProtocol_0_g$`

What's more if I remove the @JsProperty annotation I get no change to the generated code...

Update:
What does work is

```
   public native void setExtractUrlsWithoutProtocol(boolean extractUrlsWIthoutProtocol_)
/*-{
    this.extractUrlsWithoutProtocol = extractUrlsWIthoutProtocol_;
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I assume you're talking about GWT 2.8. If other, my answer doesn't apply.

I think you're missing a `@JsType` annotation on the class (not sure about this, but I think the GWT compiler might be ignoring types not annotated with `@JsType`, even though you do have `@JsProperty`).
Also, if your problem is ONLY when compiling in production mode, please be aware that you need a special compiler flag - `generateJsInteropExports` (the default is NOT to honor JS Interop annotations).

Comment: Adding @JsType and ensuring -generateJsInteropExports is on makes no difference

Comment: added the @JsType to my original question

Comment: How about your Options class? Can you find this name with a simple text search in your output JS? I'm asking because compiler discards stuff that doesn't match certain restrictions (and look for [WARN] statements in your output).
This document describes those restrictions:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/10fmlEYIHcyead_4R1S5wKGs1t2I7Fnp_PaNaa7XTEk0/edit

Comment: Also, you might want to try with a no-arg constructor. It doesn't say so in the doc, but it does mention that when using native types you have troubles without no-arg constructors.

Comment: Thanks for your help... for some reason it started working ;-). Not 100% sure why. Maybe because I restarted the compiler server I don't know

Comment: Sorry to nitpick; was just wondering how you're checking that "it's working". If you're simply including the .nocache.js and run a script that makes use of those functions, you will be getting some sort of race conditions (because .nocache.js loads browser-specific permutations asynchronously).
I'd advise to text-search your output JS first.

Comment: So, the answer was `-generateJsInteropExports` only and not `@JsType`?

Comment: I don't really know tbh. If you don't use`-generateJsInteropExports`, then definitely you don't have exports. On `@JsType`, I don't know.
Also, see my last comment above: with the async loading of JS, it is easy to get tricked and think it doesn't work, if you're simply invoking the code from a different JS (it happened to me).

Comment: yes, according to my reading of the docs I shouldn't need @JsType. Btw, the finished project is at https://github.com/Afrozaar/gwt-twitter-text I ended up using gin bindings to ensure the java script was injected before everything. Also means I can just install a module and then inject the class that has the jsinterop bindings on it. Would love to spend more time on it but other priorities :-(